# How to copy files within the same directory to another subfolder using perl

Tags: perl, server

I have one folder called test/first and in that there are few folders and files. Basically I need to copy the files having '.log' anywhere in the file name to be copied to another folder within test/first

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $source_dir = "/test/first";
my $dest_dir = "/test/first/second";

my @files = glob("$source_dir/*");

foreach my $file (@files){
  if ($file =~ /\.log/) {
  #print ("$file");
   move($file, "$dest_dir/$file");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) to extract the filename from the path.

The problem with your script is, its resolving destination directory as like this - `/test/first/second/first/a.log` where `/test/first/second/first/` doesn't exists.

Try the below script, which would do the work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;

my $source_dir = "/test/first";
my $dest_dir = "/test/first/second";

my @files = glob("$source_dir/*");

foreach my $file (@files){
    my ($fname, $dir) = fileparse($file);
    if ($fname=~ /\.log/) {
        print "Running: moving $file, $dest_dir/$fname\n";
        move($file, "$dest_dir/$fname");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just specify the target of `move` as a directory, per [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3A%3ACopy#move): `move($file, $dest_dir)`  _(If the destination already exists and is a directory, and the source is not a directory, then the source file will be renamed into the directory specified by the destination.)_